# MySQL: Changing trigger definition based on the SET columns within an INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO `users votes` SET `forumtopicid` = '$id'
INSERT INTO `users votes` SET `forumtopicid` = '$forumtopicid', `replyid` = '$id'
```

Now here is my current trigger definition:

```
UPDATE `forum topics` ft
        SET votes = votes + 1
        WHERE NEW.forumtopicid = ft.id
```

I want to change it so if the INSERT contains `replyid`, than the UPDATE becomes:

```
UPDATE `forum replies` fr
        SET votes = votes + 1
        WHERE NEW.replyid = fr.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an `if` statement in the trigger:

```
if new.replyid is null then
    UPDATE `forum topics` ft
            SET votes = votes + 1
            WHERE NEW.forumtopicid = ft.id;
else
    UPDATE `forum replies` fr
            SET votes = votes + 1
            WHERE NEW.replyid = fr.id;
end if;
```